# Find all the values for $x$: $\sin(x) < 0,6$

Tags: inequality

$\sin(x) < 0.6$

My solution is

$x<\arcsin(0.6) +2kπ$ OR $x<\pi-\arcsin(0.6) +2k\pi$

$x<0.6435+2k\pi$   OR   $x<2.4981+2k\pi$

This is correct but how can I put these in an interval? Also when I pick $\frac{\pi}2$ which is smaller than $2.4981$ the sinus is $1$???

Comment: Show us how you found $0.6435$ and $2.4981$. If you can find all the points where $\sin(x)=0.6$ then you can use that information to find all the places where $\sin(x)$ greater or less than $0.6$.

Comment: Drawing a graph should also help you. You've found the points correctly but think about whether you've shown that $\sin(x)<0.6$ or $\sin(x)>0.6$.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the post.

Comment: Each of your intervals should be bounded on both sides. You've got $x<0.6435$ which means every negative $x$ is allowed. But that's clearly not the case. What number do you think you should use if you needed to make your interval $\ldots<x<0.6435$?

Comment: BTW don't ever bother with writing $0.6435$ instead of $\arcsin .6$ or $2.4981$ instead of $\pi - \arcsin .6$.  *NOBODY* cares what the decimal values are and seeing the decimal values *instead* of the values in what they *mean* trigonometric make things *worse*.  I would deduct points for giving me decimal values.   it's irritating becuase of course calculators give you decimal values.  But I'll tell you *NOBODY* wants to know what the decimal values are.

Comment: If you wish you can replace $0.64354$ with $0.2048\pi$ and $0.6435$ with $0.7952\pi$ but... I assure you, *NOBODY* will be happy if you do.

Comment: @fleablood, my teacher is :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use common sense.

$\sin x$ starts at $x=0; \sin x=0$ and it immediately increases as $x$ increases.  At $x = \arcsin .6$ then $\sin x= .6$.  $0 < \arcsin .6 < \frac \pi 2$.  Let's call $\arcsin .6 = \alpha$.  So that's our first interval: For $x \in [0, \alpha), \sin x < .6$.

And for all $k \in \mathbb Z$ we get $x \in [2k\pi, 2k\pi + \alpha)$ then $\sin x< .6$.

Now $\sin x$ is symmetric and $\sin x = \sin (\pi - x)$ so for $x = \pi -\alpha$ we will get $\sin x = .6$ again but for the interval $x \in [\alpha, \pi - \alpha]$ we will have $\sin x \ge .6$.

Now for $\pi-\alpha < x < \pi$ we have $\sin x$ decreasing so $x \in (\pi-\alpha, \pi]$ we will have $\sin x < .6$.

And for all integer $k$ we get $((2k+1)\pi - \alpha, (2k+1)\pi]$ we will have $\sin x < .6$.

Now for $\pi < x < 2\pi$ we have $\sin x$ is negative and therefore less than $.6$.  So we have $x\in (\pi, 2\pi)$ then $\sin x \le .6$.

Or in general, if $x \in ((2k-1) \pi, 2k\pi)$ then $\sin x \le .6$.

So in doing on $2\pi$ period we have $\sin x \le .6$ if $x \in [0, \alpha)$ or $x \in (\pi-\alpha, \pi]$ or $x \in (\pi, 2\pi)$.  Combining those we get $\sin x < .6$ if $x\in [0, \alpha)$ or $(\pi-\alpha, 2\pi)$.

Putting in the general period we get $\sin x < .6$ if $x\in [2k\pi, 2k\pi + \alpha)$ or $x \in ((2k-1)\pi - \alpha, 2k \pi)$.

Combining we get $\sin x < .6$ if $x \in ((2k-1)\pi - \alpha, 2k\pi + \alpha)$

> My solution is
>   x  < arcsin(0.6)+2kπ
>    OR x<π−arcsin(0.6)+2kπ

Well, you aren't restricting to intervals.  It works if $x < \arcsin .6$ but not if $x > \arcsin .6$.  You can't just start with $x < \alpha$ and then just add $2k\pi$ to it. That would make you also insculde everything between $\alpha$ and $2k\pi$ and you *know* its not true for all of those values!

And as $k $ can be *any* integer then *every* value $x < \arcsin .6 + 2\pi k $ for *some* $k$!!!

When you (didn't) say $x < \arcsin .6$ it was understood you were restricting yourself to $-\frac \pi 2 \le x < \arcsin .6$.  and when you (should have)  said $x  > \pi - \arcsin .6$ it was underston you were restricting yourself to $\pi - \arcsin .6 < x < 2\pi$.

So if you add $2k\pi$ to these you get $2k\pi -\frac \pi 2 \le x < \arcsin. 6 + 2k\pi$.  And $2k\pi + \pi - \arcsin .6 < x < 2\pi + 2k\pi$.  If we adjust and combine those we get $(2k-1)\pi -\arcsin .6 < x < 2k\pi + \arcsin .6$.

[And we *DON'T* get the result if $2k\pi + \arcsin. 6 \le x \le (2k_1)\pi - \arcsin .6$]

Comment: THANKS! I get it now it should be $x>\pi-\arcsin(0.6) +2k\pi$. If we know this we can say x should be lower than $53°$ and greater than $143°$ which is equal to an interval of: $x ∈ ]2,4981 +2kπ; 6,9267+2kπ[$

Answer (score 1):

Look at the definition of $\arcsin$ function. The return value is in the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. So the first thing is in this interval you get $$-\pi/2\le x\le\arcsin 0.6$$
You can write this as $$x\in[-\pi/2,\arcsin(0.6)]$$
You can now translate by $2k\pi$ and use the union of these intervals $$x\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z}[-\pi/2+2k\pi,\arcsin(0.6)+2k\pi]$$
Note however that you also have solutions in the $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ or eqivalent intervals.